# How I would perform the following matrix operations?

Tags: calculus, matrices, matrix-equations

Does anyone know how I would perform the following matrix operations? Thank you.

> $$ A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}, C= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}. $$ (a)  $|A^4|$
> (b) $A^{-1}$
> (c) $D = A^{-1}C$
> (d) $AD - C$

Answer (score 1):

You multiply rows by columns. So, AC would equal in this case:

$$
AC = \matrix { \left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
1^2 + 2 + 2 & 1^2 + 0 + 1^2 \\
2 + 2 + 4 & 2 + 0 + 2 \\
1 + 2 + 4 & 1 + 0 + 2 \\
\end {array}
\right] }
= \matrix { \left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
5 & 2 \\
8 & 4 \\
7 & 3
\end {array}
\right] }
$$

In order to multiply, the first matrix must have **just as many columns as the amount of rows for the second matrix.** Also note that matrix multiplication is *not commutative*, in that $$ AC \ne CA $$ (Try it and see if you come up with the same product.)

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**. The formula $\det(XY) = \det(X)\det(Y)$ should help you to reduce (a) to computing $\det(A)$. Knowing $\det(A)$ might also help you to solve (b). From there, (c) should be easy. For (d), if $D = A^{-1}C$, what is $AD$?